# Android - Registering a Receiver from a Static 'helper' Method (can't get context)?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-context, android-broadcast

Now that the `PROVIDERS_CHANGED` intent-filter can't be set in the Manifest, I'm doing it dynamically.
However, I need to register/unregister the dynamically coded Receiver in multiple places.
Due to this, I am creating a "Helper" Class that contains a static method with the Receiver code.

**MY ISSUE:** I can't seem to figure out how to get the Context in order to register/unregister receiver.

**Here is my current code:**

```
public class GpsReceiverHelper {

public static void gpsReceiverCode() {

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED");

    final BroadcastReceiver gpsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction() != null &&
                    intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {

                //  RECEIVER CODE HERE

            }
        }
    };
    this.registerReceiver(gpsReceiver, intentFilter);
    //  THIS IS WHERE I CAN'T GET A CONTEXT (USING "this" OR OTHERWISE)

}
}
```

**MY QUESTIONS:**
**(A) -** How can I go about retrieving a `context` here?
**(B) -** Is creating a helper class with a `public static` method the right way to be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I go about retrieving a context here?

Pass it in as a parameter (`public static void gpsReceiverCode(Context context)`).

> I need to register/unregister the dynamically coded Receiver in multiple places

When your receiver was in the manifest, it was "registered" in one place. Hence, when you do it dynamically, you can register it in one place (e.g., custom `Application` subclass).

> Is creating a helper class with a public static method the right way to be doing this?

Probably not, insofar as you probably should not be needing to use this code in 2+ places.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The reason I need to register and unregister it in multiple places, is because the GPS-Listener is a Preference in my App, which can be turned on and off.. Right now, there are 4 places in my App which I previously either Registered or Unregistered the Receiver from the Manifest - but now must do this dynamically.. A couple times in my Settings Fragment (for obvious reasons) and also in my BOOT_RECEIVED Broadcast Receiver.. So can I do this by making calls to my Helper method? Or must I do this using the full code each time? Whats the alternative?

Comment: @Studio2bDesigns: "is because the GPS-Listener is a Preference in my App, which can be turned on and off" -- you could use a `boolean` in the `BroadcastReceiver` to determine whether it does anything, rather than registering/unregistering the receiver every time. "So can I do this by making calls to my Helper method?" -- sure, just pass in the `Context` to the method.

Comment: I will try passing the Context as you suggested.. To better explain the way I'm using the Receiver: The receiver has the `PROVIDERS_CHANGED` intent-filter, and inside the code it checks if GPS has become available, and if so, it proceeds with some code.. In my `Settings` fragment, it turns it on or off.. In my `BOOT_RECEIVED` receiver, it determines the User Settings, and either registers or unregisters as needed.. Assuming you're suggesting to check for User-Setting within the Receiver itself, I would still need to make this check inside `BOOT_RECEIVED` & whether it's registered

Comment: In other words, on `BOOT_RECEIVED`, lets say the User-Setting is turned ON, but the check says the Receiver is OFF.. Or, the User-Setting is turned OFF, but the check says the Receiver is ON.. I would need to correct this.. Is there a way to check if a dynamically-registered receiver is on or off, and turn it on or off, from a separate class?

Comment: @Studio2bDesigns: At boot time, by definition, your dynamically-registered receiver is not registered. Such a receiver is registered only while your process is running. When Android terminates your process, the receiver is gone. A reboot, among other things, terminates all running processes.

Comment: Ok, so that being the case, inside my BOOT receiver, I will need to (A) check the User-Setting, and (B) if the Setting is Enabled, I will need to re-register the Receiver.. But since the Receiver contains quite a bit of code, it would be inefficient to be putting it in multiple places (the BOOT receiver, the SETTINGS fragment, etc).. So now that you know how I'm using it, IS using a Helper class with a static method for registering and containing the code for the GpsReceiver the best way to go about doing this (as you previously said "probably not" to)..?

Comment: PS. Should my "helper class" (as I posted above) be 'extending' anything? such as BroadcastReceiver, or Activity, etc? right now the name of the Class is grey for some reason - and so is the Method name.

Comment: PPS. Do I need to put an empty constructor inside the dynamically registered receiver, similar to how a manifest-registered receiver requires one?

Comment: @Studio2bDesigns: "IS using a Helper class with a static method for registering and containing the code for the GpsReceiver the best way to go about doing this" -- in Java, yes. "Should my "helper class" (as I posted above) be 'extending' anything?" -- no. "right now the name of the Class is grey for some reason - and so is the Method name" -- that means the IDE is not seeing any other code reference it.

Comment: "Do I need to put an empty constructor inside the dynamically registered receiver, similar to how a manifest-registered receiver requires one?" -- a manifest-registered receiver does not require that you write a constructor. What all components (activities, services, receivers) require is that there be a `public` zero-argument constructor that the framework can use to create instances of those components. If you do not write any constructor, you get a `public` zero-argument constructor by default.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! You are extremely generous and helpful.. I'll go ahead and "accept" your Answer, and add to your already-insanely-high reputation (lol). You deserve it. Hopefully if I end up having another quick question you'll be willing to swing back by to answer. Thanks again.

Comment: **Question..** How would I go about checking whether a dynamically-registered broadcastreceiver is currently enabled? In the past, I've always used the packagemanager to check for a manifest-registered receivers status, but how would I do this for a dynamic-registered receiver?

Comment: @Studio2bDesigns: You are the one who registered it. When the registering `Context` gets destroyed, or when you unregister it, it is unregistered. You need to keep track of those conditions yourself. In the case of the `Application` context, the "gets destroyed" scenario doesn't exist, so it's merely a question of whether you unregister it yourself.

Comment: My Receiver will be getting enabled/disabled based upon the User's Preference within my App Settings screen - this is why I wanted to check the state before making the change, to avoid redundancy.. But **more important**, I've noticed if I toggle the Setting that controls the Receiver on/off multiple times in a short period of time, it crashes my App.. How would you recommend avoiding this happening, in case the user toggles the preference on/off too quickly?

Comment: @Studio2bDesigns: "I've noticed if I toggle the Setting that controls the Receiver on/off multiple times in a short period of time, it crashes my App" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash. If you cannot determine how to avoid the crash, ask a separate Stack Overflow question. There, you can provide a [mcve], including the stack trace and the code that generates it.

Comment: As opposed to using static methods in my code (above), would it be more proper to be using public methods (non-static), and in my calling classes just put something like `private ReceiverHelperClass receiverHelper = new ReceiverHelperClass` and then do `receiverHelper.methodCall()`?

Comment: @Studio2bDesigns: Probably not, unless `ReceiverHelperClass` is going to have some state (i.e., fields).

Comment: Somebody on another post had suggested doing as I described, in order to make it a "true" helper class, rather than calling the static methods. I wonder why you guys have different opinions, as you both have a very high reputation. I guess I'll stick with static and hope for the best.